# Google Sheets - Replace Duplicate cells with =[cell]

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a google sheet with duplicate cell values. I was wondering if there's a quick and easy way to replace all those duplicates with a reference to just one of them, i.e "=[cell]".

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible to do with formula.

[image]

Paste this in B2 and copy the formula down:

`=if(countif($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"["&ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,A:A,0),COLUMN(A2),4)&"]",A2)`

Then to get actual cell refference, use script:

1. this formula makes text looking like reference: `=if(countif($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"="&ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,A:A,0),COLUMN(A2),4),A2)`
2. script must `getValues` and then `setFormulas` to range `B2:B`